# TokenError :unauthorized in passport-google-oauth20

Tags: express, passport.js

**when I try to use google oauth20 then getting this error**
TokenError: Unauthorized
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (C:\Users\Rupesh\Desktop\Projects\storybook1\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:329:12)
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (C:\Users\Rupesh\Desktop\Projects\storybook1\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:376:16)
    at C:\Users\Rupesh\Desktop\Projects\storybook1\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:166:45
    at C:\Users\Rupesh\Desktop\Projects\storybook1\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:191:18
    at passBackControl (C:\Users\Rupesh\Desktop\Projects\storybook1\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage. (C:\Users\Rupesh\Desktop\Projects\storybook1\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:157:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1081:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

`please help`

Answer (score 17):

there was a typo in clientSecret. If you are facing the same problem then make sure that you have checked clientID and clientSecret .
Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem

Comment: Is it soved your problem or not ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same error in 2K22.
You just need to go to **Credentials** => **OAuth 2.0 Client App** => **Reset Secret**
*Note: It may take 5 minutes to a few hours for settings to take effect*
and that's fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check a clientID && clientSecret is a valid or not.